# Run Embedded Jetty Server in Background on Linux

Tags: linux, jetty

I'm using a ssh session on a Linux server to start an Embedded Jetty Server to run a web application that exposes web services.  When I use the java -jar start.jar to bring up the Jetty web server instance I don't have access to the command line in that session and must open up a new ssh session in order to run a command line application that invokes the web services running on the jetty instance.  Is there any way to run jetty in the background and in the same ssh session have access to the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at nohup, and as I recommended on the mailing list when you asked this same question, get to know the 'screen' utility, it is a wonderful tool to have in your toolbox.